# Call Transfer from Queue if the call is reached Timeout (EXITWITHTIMEOUT)

Tags: asterisk

I am using queue(Queue,Rn,,,20) dialplan. If call is holds in queue more than 20 minutes. I need to transfer the call to some other extension without hangup.

Please suggest the way to achieve the above scenario. Thanks..

Comment: exten => _X.,3,Queue(QueueName,Rn,,,20)
exten => _X.,4,Dial(DAHDI/g1/XXXXXX)     I Transfered the call by using above things... It is working.. thanks @arheops

Answer (score 0):

5th param of queue is queue timeout.

If it reached, variable QUESTATUS will be set to TIMEOUT

You can check that in dialplan, if timeout do any other action.

> pro-sip*CLI> core show application Queue
>
> -= Info about application 'Queue' =-
>
> [Synopsis] Queue a call for a call queue.
>
> [Description] In addition to transferring the call, a call may be
>   parked and then picked up by another user. This application will
>   return to the dialplan if the queue does not exist, or any of the join
>   options cause the caller to not enter the queue. This application does
>   not automatically answer and should be preceeded by an application
>   such as Answer(), Progress(), or Ringing(). This application sets the
>   following channel variable upon completion: ${QUEUESTATUS}: The status
>   of the call as a text string.
>       TIMEOUT
>       FULL
>       JOINEMPTY
>       LEAVEEMPTY
>       JOINUNAVAIL
>       LEAVEUNAVAIL
>       CONTINUE
>
> [Syntax]
>   Queue(queuename[,options[,URL[,announceoverride[,timeout[,AGI[,macro[,gosub[,rule[,position]]]]]]]]])
>
> [Arguments] options
>       C: Mark all calls as "answered elsewhere" when cancelled.
>
> ```
> c: Continue in the dialplan if the callee hangs up.
>
> d: data-quality (modem) call (minimum delay).
>
> h: Allow *callee* to hang up by pressing '*'.
>
> H: Allow *caller* to hang up by pressing '*'.
>
> n: No retries on the timeout; will exit this application and go to
> the next step.
>
> i: Ignore call forward requests from queue members and do nothing
> when they are requested.
>
> I: Asterisk will ignore any connected line update requests or any
> redirecting party update requests it may receive on this dial attempt.
>
> r: Ring instead of playing MOH. Periodic Announcements are still
> made, if applicable.
>
> R: Ring instead of playing MOH when a member channel is actually
> ringing.
>
> t: Allow the *called* user to transfer the calling user.
>
> T: Allow the *calling* user to transfer the call.
>
> w: Allow the *called* user to write the conversation to disk via
> Monitor.
>
> W: Allow the *calling* user to write the conversation to disk via
> Monitor.
>
> k: Allow the *called* party to enable parking of the call by sending
> the DTMF sequence defined for call parking in "features.conf".
>
> K: Allow the *calling* party to enable parking of the call by sending
> the DTMF sequence defined for call parking in "features.conf".
>
> x: Allow the *called* user to write the conversation to disk via
> MixMonitor.
>
> X: Allow the *calling* user to write the conversation to disk via
> MixMonitor.
> ```
>
> URL
>        will be sent to the called party if the channel supports it. timeout
>       Will cause the queue to fail out after a specified number of seconds,
>       checked between each "queues.conf"  and  cycle. AGI
>       Will setup an AGI script to be executed on the calling party's channel
>       once they are connected to a queue member. macro
>       Will run a macro on the called party's channel (the queue member)
>       once the parties are connected. gosub
>       Will run a gosub on the called party's channel (the queue member)
>       once the parties are connected. rule
>       Will cause the queue's defaultrule to be overridden by the rule
>       specified. position
>       Attempt to enter the caller into the queue at the numerical position
>       specified. '1' would attempt to enter the caller at the head of the queue,
>       and '3' would attempt to place the caller third in the queue.
>
> [See Also] Queue(), QueueLog(), AddQueueMember(), RemoveQueueMember(),
>   PauseQueueMember(), UnpauseQueueMember(), QUEUE_VARIABLES,
>   QUEUE_MEMBER, QUEUE_MEMBER_COUNT, QUEUE_EXISTS, QUEUE_WAITING_COUNT,
>   QUEUE_MEMBER_LIST, QUEUE_MEMBER_PENALT